# Can't delete or update a row in Oracle table. Fails with ORA-08103: object no longer exists

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-text

`delete from table1 where ROWID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';`

```
SQL Error: ORA-29876: failed in the execution of the ODCIINDEXDELETE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10602: failed to queue DML change to column Col1 for primary key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
DRG-50857: oracle error in drekqkd(execute k_stmt)
ORA-08103: object no longer exists
```

Please don't send me to contact oracle support :)

Comment: Do you have an invalid index on this table?

Comment: yep that was the case. We had to drop and recreate the index

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to drop and create again the text index (indextype is ctxsys.context) for the column